# Joomla JFactory Class in module

Tags: joomla

I made a module which after receive &_POST the details from external server will select the tables from database and update the table cell. but: Between the 'if' statement, the jFactory Class is not working i mean i can not call username using $user->username but if i call the $user->username before the 'if' statement everything works fine. Could you help me with this and tell why its not working correctly

```
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']=='IP NUMBER' && !empty($_POST)){

  $xxx      = $_POST['xxx']; 
  $zzz  = $_POST['zzz']; 
  $yyy      = $_POST['yyy']; 


}
```

The post variables are received from external server

Have you any idea ?

I need to add that $_post from the exterran server is receive with a delay but module is active all time..

Comment: The code you provided doesn't interfere with JFactory at all. You need to provide REAL pieces of working and non-working codes.

Comment: Have you by any chance defined `$user` inside an `if` statement and are trying to call if somewhere else, where it doesn't apply? try defining `$user` at the top of your file, outside any statements

Comment: yes i think i try all combination to get it work :/